# Add a video to a playlist using resumable upload

Tags: c#, youtube-api

Does anyone know how to add a video to a playlist when using resumable upload?

Let me make this clear. Below is my code.

```
Video newVideo = new Video();
newVideo.Title = fileName.Split(".".ToCharArray())[0];
newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Nonprofit", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
newVideo.Description = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;
ResumableUploader m_ResumableUploader = null;
Authenticator YouTubeAuthenticator;

m_ResumableUploader = new ResumableUploader(100); //chunksize 1 MB
m_ResumableUploader.AsyncOperationCompleted += new AsyncOperationCompletedEventHandler(m_ResumableUploader_AsyncOperationCompleted);
m_ResumableUploader.AsyncOperationProgress += new AsyncOperationProgressEventHandler(m_ResumableUploader_AsyncOperationProgress);

YouTubeAuthenticator = new ClientLoginAuthenticator("YouTubeUploader", ServiceNames.YouTube, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["USERNAME"].ToString(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PASSWORD"].ToString());

YouTubeAuthenticator.DeveloperKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DEVELOPER_KEY"].ToString();
string contentType = MediaFileSource.GetContentTypeForFileName(fileName);
newVideo.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource(filePath, contentType);

AtomLink link = new AtomLink("http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/resumable/feeds/api/users/<username>/uploads");
link.Rel = ResumableUploader.CreateMediaRelation;
newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Links.Add(link);

System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);

m_ResumableUploader.InsertAsync(YouTubeAuthenticator, newVideo.YouTubeEntry, new object());
```

I am trying to upload a video directly to a playlist.

I am looking at this code and I am having a difficult time connecting the two. Need help.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet

Adding a video to a playlist

You can add a video to a playlist by using a PlayListMember object. The following code creates a PlayListMember object with a known ID value and then adds it to the Playlist object (p). Since the request does not specify a position where the video will appear in the playlist, the new video is added to the end of the playlist.

```
 // For Playlist object p
 PlayListMember pm = new PlayListMember();
 // Insert <id> or <videoid> for video here
 pm.Id = VIDEOID;
 request.AddToPlaylist(p, pm);
```

**Update 1 - I get an "Unsupported URI format" error when adding to playlist.**

```
YouTubeRequestSettings ys = new YouTubeRequestSettings("YouTubeUploader",
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DEVELOPER_KEY"].ToString());
YouTubeRequest ytr = new YouTubeRequest(ys);
Video v = ytr.ParseVideo(e.ResponseStream);                  
PlayListMember pm = new PlayListMember();
Feed<Playlist> userPlaylists = ytr.GetPlaylistsFeed(ytr.Credentials.Username);
foreach (Playlist p in userPlaylists.Entries)
{
     fs.WriteLine(p.Title);
     if (p.Title == "Test 2")
     {
          pm.Id = v.VideoId;
          ytr.AddToPlaylist(p, pm);

          fs.WriteLine("Added To Playlist ");
     }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [YouTube API - Adding a video to a playlist using resumable upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976749/youtube-api-adding-a-video-to-a-playlist-using-resumable-upload)

Comment: Yes a duplicate of its own question, but this time is well documented. I think we should appreciate the effort now

Comment: Ok. Now can I get a response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The code on YouTube has an error in it. It tells you to set the PlayListMember id to the VIDEOID.

```
 // For Playlist object p
 PlayListMember pm = new PlayListMember();
 // Insert <id> or <videoid> for video here
 pm.Id = VIDEOID;
 request.AddToPlaylist(p, pm);
```

That is incorrect. You need to set the VIDEOID to the PlayListMember VideoID

```
 // For Playlist object p
 PlayListMember pm = new PlayListMember();
 // Insert <id> or <videoid> for video here
 pm.VideoId = VIDEOID;
 request.AddToPlaylist(p, pm);
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that, and sorry about the bad info in the developer's guide. I put in a request to get that updated so that others aren't led astray in the future.

Answer (score 0):

What links the two operations is the video id. You need to get the video id from the first part (the upload) and supply it to the second part (the playlist insert). So the question boils down to how you get the video id of the new video when performing a resumable upload using the .NET client library.

I think this sample code specifically deals with that: http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/samples/YouTubeUploader/YouTubeUploader/insertandretry.cs#169

Comment: I am getting a Unsupported URI format error when trying to add to an existing playlist. See Update above.

Comment: Have you done a sanity check to ensure that v.VideoId is being properly set?

Comment: Yes. The videoid is being set

Comment: It looks like it's getting thrown at http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/src/core/utilities.cs#409 but I can't tell you exactly why. A good place to follow-up is http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/issues/list since it appears to be a problem specific to the .NET client library.