# How To Get the ID for Uploaded Video to YouTube Using Resumable Upload

Tags: c#, .net, youtube-api, youtube.net-api

I am using Async ResumableUpload to upload videos to YouTube however I have not been able to retrieve the VideoID for the successfully uploaded video. This was very easy for the single Sync uploads but I have been unable to find any examples for the Async.

Here's the code:

```
        var mResumableUploader = new ResumableUploader(chunkSize);
        mResumableUploader.AsyncOperationCompleted += MResumableUploaderAsyncOperationCompleted;
        mResumableUploader.AsyncOperationProgress += MResumableUploaderAsyncOperationProgress;

        var youTubeAuthenticator = new ClientLoginAuthenticator(appName, ServiceNames.YouTube, uName, passWord);
        youTubeAuthenticator.DeveloperKey = devKey;

        newVideo = new Video();

        newVideo.Title = "video";
        newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Entertainment", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
        newVideo.Keywords = "video";
        newVideo.Description = "video";
        newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;
        newVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource(fileName, fileContType);

        var link = new AtomLink("http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/resumable/feeds/api/users/default/uploads");
        link.Rel = ResumableUploader.CreateMediaRelation;
        newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Links.Add(link);

        Console.WriteLine("Starting upload: ");
        mResumableUploader.InsertAsync(youTubeAuthenticator, newVideo.YouTubeEntry, "inserter");
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990945/add-a-video-to-a-playlist-using-resumable-upload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown on google data provided samples you can parse the video after the upload process is completed.
Regards

```
        ru.AsyncOperationCompleted += new AsyncOperationCompletedEventHandler(ru_AsyncOperationCompleted);

void ru_AsyncOperationCompleted(object sender, AsyncOperationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            //upload complete
            YouTubeRequestSettings ytSettings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("myApp", googleDevKey, ytUsername, ytPassword);
            Video v = ytRequest.ParseVideo(e.ResponseStream);
            string videoId = v.VideoId;
            string watchPage = v.WatchPage.ToString();

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

With YouTube API v3 you don't need to use ResumableUploader. You just need to add a delegate to the VideoInsertRequest ResponseReceived:

```
var video = new Video();
video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
video.Snippet.Title = "Default Video Title";
video.Status = new VideoStatus();
video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "unlisted"; // or "private" or "public"
var filePath = @"REPLACE_ME.mp4"; // Replace with path to actual movie file.

using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
{
  var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
  videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;
  await videosInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
}

void videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived(Video video)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Video id '{0}' was successfully uploaded.", video.Id);
}
```

The complete code is here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#upload_a_video